# Reopen this. It's not localized

Tags: discussion, status-completed, too-localized

[How to install a program that self-downloads from the web, from behind a corporate firewall?](https://superuser.com/questions/547304/behind-corporate-proxy-cant-install-program-that-self-downloads-from-the-web/547389#comment664510_547389)

There are gazillions of people trying to make things work behind a corporate proxy. Why on earth is installing ANY software behind a corporate firewall/proxy TOO localized??

Answer (score 14):

I edited the question to be a little bit more generic, and I opened it for you. In this case I think it's a bit of a border-line situation. It's pretty specific to your corporate firewall settings (and corporate policies, too), but the general advice of "how to deal with web installers when behind a proxy" could certainly be useful for other people.

On an unrelated note though, if you're asking for a question to be re-opened, it helps your case to be polite. Making demands and getting upset isn't productive to solving the problem. If you'd like a question re-opened, posting on meta is fine, but just stick to politely explaining *why* you think the question isn't too localized (or off topic or whyever it was closed), and stay away from ranting or making demands.

Even if you've been a user since the first day (and your claim of "I've been a user for YEARS" is false anyhow; [you've been here 9 months](https://superuser.com/users/129981/george-katsanos)), you're still required to be nice and keep questions on-topic. You haven't even answered any questions on Super User - just asked - so you hardly have a right to make demands.

Answer (score 6):

> **This question is unlikely to help any future visitors**; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or **an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet**. For help making this question
>   more broadly applicable.

Why the "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet"?

Because we have no idea about which proxy is used, how it's configured, what it's blocking, etc, etc. So, the answers (or likely, the guesses) will be highly debatable.

And if you're lucky, one of the answers will work for you, but it's no guarantee that the same answer will work for someone else, when there are *gazillions* of proxies out there. Thus, the "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: The proxy configuration has nothing to do with my question -no effect,at all. Most corp. proxies behave similarly -> blocking a number of ports and asking authentication to connect to any external network. This is a problem happening with any executable which attempts to fetch data from the web - one notable example, Google Chrome. Closing questions like that will only make SO unpopular. I've been using the website for years and I demand at least SOME respect to how my questions are being treated. Manner that's called.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: Sorry, I, and 4 other users who close-voted the question, have obviously no manners.